# Code snippet editor is not loading in Chrome!

Tags: bug, status-declined, stack-overflow, google-chrome, stack-snippets

I don't know whether this is a bug or security issue with chrome. But I'm getting a screen like this when I click on the snippet button. Any help would be helpful.

[image]

**Chrome Console**

This is what I'm getting when clicking on the snippet button

[image]

**Network**

[image]

**OS** : Windows 7 Professional 64-bit

**Browser** : ChromeVersion 54.0.2840.6 dev-m (64-bit)

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the browser dev tools? Anything in the network tab? Anything in the console? What browser/OS (and versions)?

Comment: @Oded Please check my updated answer

Comment: And the network tab (after a page refresh and trying to show the code snippet editor)?

Comment: I have no repro on Chrome/ Win10.

Comment: For what it's worth no repro on OS X / Chrome

Comment: @Oded please check my updated answer

Comment: I have some weirdness with scripts failing to load when I switch between `https://` and `http://` but those resolve themselves after a reload. Are you using any  plugins that force your connection to https?

Comment: @rene ok.. I removed some added extensions and restarted but still the same!

Comment: We do not support browsers that are in beta state - Chrome canary is not supported.

Comment: Not only is 54 not yet in beta, it is in the dev channel - alpha software. We don't support that either.

Comment: See this for details: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need

Comment: thats clear now. Thanks.